# Unable to install fastai on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: anaconda, pytorch, conda, fast-ai

I'm currently trying to get fastai installed on a conda environment using the command `conda install -c fastai fastai` as shown in the installation [guide](https://github.com/fastai/fastai/blob/master/README.md#installation). This is what appears when that command is ran:

```
(fastai) C:\>conda install -v -c fastai fastai
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... Unable to retrieve repodata (response: 404) for https://conda.anaconda.org/fastai/win-64/current_repodata.json

done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: ...working... failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: ...working...
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 82, in do_call
    return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_install.py", line 20, in execute
    install(args, parser, 'install')
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 308, in install
    raise e
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versionsThe following specifications were found to be incompatible with your CUDA driver:

  - feature:/win-64::__cuda==9.2=0

Your installed CUDA driver is: 9.2
```

I can't say I completely understand what the issue is here. I previously thought it was an issue with PyTorch but after installing PyTorch successfully, I am still greeted with this message. Any ideas on how I can this package installed on my environment? Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What's up with CUDA? It appears to be a problem for non-obvious reasons. Did you try out to remove it before installation (and reinstall it afterwards)?

Comment: No, I haven't. I'll give this a go.

Comment: Can you share the contents of the environment?

Comment: @AMC Currently I'm running conda on Windows 10 with a NVIDIA GeForce 1050 GPU. The conda environment is using Python 3.8. Is there more info you need that I've missed?

Answer (score 1):

Try downgrading from python3.8 to python 3.7, it works for me.